# How to define preexec and precmd in broune shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using following bash version

> GNU bash, version 2.04.0(1)-release (powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu)

I want some command to be executed before shell starts to execute the command passed by user.

I want the output like this:

> sw0:FID128:root> pwd
>
> Wed Apr 22 06:00:09 UTC 2015  <- **date command should be executed by sh. first**
>
> /root  <- **Then user passed command should be executed by shell**
>
> sw0:FID128:root>

Note:

1) I have already tried "PROMPT_COMMAND", PROMPT_COMMAND is executed by shell after processing the command passed by user. So this one is ruled out.(My shell version is ancient one)

2) I have tried trap with DEBUG too,this also led to the same result as above. Even in this case DEBUG signal handler was executed after processing user's input command only.

3) Then i thought of using preexec and precmd,but these things seems to be not supported by bash,so how how do i achieve equivalent of these commands in bash

Please help me on this

Comment: Do you really want als bash commands scrambled? Also standard system scripts? Or can you define your own shell for this ? `while [ 1 ]; do read -r cmd; date; eval "${cmd}"; sleep 1; echo ${PS1}; done`

Comment: Walter,i 'm not defining my own shell,i need the running system shell to do this.

Comment: Not sure the your version of the GNU bash on PowerPC has all the features of readline put in place, though could you check if one of the solution posted [here](http://superuser.com/questions/117227/a-command-before-every-bash-command) or [here](http://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command) works for you?